# LAN connection repeatedly lost after some minutes

Tags: windows-xp, networking, internet-connection

I have Windows XP SP3. My internet connection works well on my mobiles, so there is no problem with my provider.

Wnen I start a browser, e.g. Chrome or IE, it works for a while but after a few minutes, the connection restarts.

I tried repairing it, but after a while it loses connection again.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We're missing details in order to be able to help you. Has this always been like that? If not, when did it start? How is your connection configured? Do you connect by Ethernet / LAN, or wirelessl? What exactly happens when the connection "restarts"? Please [edit] your question to add info.

Answer (score 1):

Is that an IBM/Lenovo system and a ThinkPad with an Intel WiFi card ?

This was a big problem with ThinkPad's and lesser known notebook makers since it seems Lenovo had the audacity to tune their drivers up enough that SP3 broke it or just cause munginating frustration, other smaller boutique laptop makers modified their drivers for varied reasons but most often the noble reason of seeking peek performance and they also had to revise their drivers.

since Lenovo injects a slew of ThinkVantage branded software like other new PC bloatware, the tight integration of customization with generic SP3 revisions results in a war behind the scenes and the connection reliability suffers the most.  If my speculation is correct, these specific links to Intelo pages offers patches and patched patches, the machine types may vary but the patches are often ubiquitous.  Hopefully this helped or sets you towards the right direction.

) Update Intel® PROSet/Wireless WiFi Connection Utility (12.1.2.0)

using one of the following links:

http://support.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/5300_5100/index.htm
(Multiple downloads for different Operating Systems)

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/filter_results.aspx?strTypes=all&ProductID=3062&OSFullName=Windows*+XP+Professional&lang=eng&strOSs=44&submit=Go!
(XP Specific)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with a thinkpad T41 with intel wireless chip. After installing Windows XP SP3 the wireless connection drops after a few seconds. Instead of removing SP3 I reinstalled drivers from Lenovo site and the wifi now works like a charm.

For

Intel PRO/1000 MT Mobile Connection

and for

Intel PRO/Wirelless LAN 2100 3B Mini PCI Adapter

find the driver file 1rwc89ww.exe at Lenovo site